# Draw dice results in ASCII

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

Show the random result of a dice toss if done with a cube shaped die, in ASCII.

```
$ dice
```

should result in one of

```
-----
|   |
| o |
|   |
-----

-----
|o  |
|   |
|  o|
-----

-----
|o  |
| o |
|  o|
-----

-----
|o o|
|   |
|o o|
-----

-----
|o o|
| o |
|o o|
-----

-----
|o o|
|o o|
|o o|
-----
```

Comment: You have not defined the metric here. Is this meant to be a code golf? It is always worth discussing possible tasks in the [puzzle lab chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/307/golf-puzzle-lab) or the [sand box on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/225/proposed-questions-sandbox) so that you can address these kinds of questions before you go live.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the metric always is the number of characters? Thanks for pointing me to the chat and then sand box on meta. If this question falls flat on it face then I will delete it. I hate to do it right now, just in case someone already started working on it.

Comment: Ah...note the site name *"Programming puzzles and code golf"* (and yeah, I thought it scanned better the other way round, too). You will also find [one-liners](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/252/78), [king-of-the-hill tournaments](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/302/78), and [code-challenges](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) (everything else, but you are still supposed to [establish an objective metric](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/305/78) for winning), so it is necessary to say and to apply the appropriate tag.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/243/is-it-ok-to-say-dice-and-dices-instead-of-die-and-dice

Comment: According to [XKCD #221](http://xkcd.com/221/), `alert('-----\n|o  o|\n|     |\n|o  o|\n-----');` is a correct program.

Comment: If you remove the ascii-art tag, I can offer my 39char-solution `print("⚀⚁⚂⚃⚄⚅"(util.Random.nextInt(6)))` (utf-art).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Golfscript, 56 characters

```
"-"5*n"|":|"o "1/:&6rand:§1<=" "&§3<=|n|&§5<=]&§2%=1$-1%
```

The solution can be [tested here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Ii0iNSpuInwiOnwibyAiMS86JjZyYW5kOsKnMTw9IiAiJsKnMzw9fG58JsKnNTw9XSbCpzIlPTEkLTEl&run=true).

Answer (score 30):

### Python, <strike>112</strike> 110 chars

```
from random import*
r=randrange(6)
C='o '
s='-----\n|'+C[r<1]+' '+C[r<3]+'|\n|'+C[r<5]
print s+C[r&1]+s[::-1]
```

Comment: Those compares in the array indexer are totally impressive!

Comment: Ditto! I like how you used the symmetry of the die as well :)

Comment: Could you use something like `id(0)%7%6`? It's not going to be a uniform distribution, but it's significantly shorter...

Comment: @Nabb: that isn't very random.  In particular, it is often the same from run to run, so it wouldn't be very useful in generating random dice rolls.

Answer (score 11):

### Ruby 1.9, 80 <s>84</s> characters

```
z=" o";$><<(s=?-*5+"
|#{z[2/~a=rand(6)]} #{z[a/3]}|
|"+z[a/5])+z[~a%2]+s.reverse
```

Comment: I liked the +`s.reverse`

Answer (score 8):

### Windows PowerShell, 89 <s>93</s> <s>96</s> <s>97</s> <s>101</s> <s>119</s> characters

```
-join('-----
|{0} {1}|
|{2}{3}'-f'o '[$(!($x=random 6);$x-lt3;$x-ne5;$x%2)])[0..14+13..0]
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Python, 109 unicode characters

```
#coding:u8
print u"鱸헓ȅ᪮ԅ᪅餠☏汁끝鐸즪聗K糉툜㣹뫡燳闣≆뤀⩚".encode("u16")[2:].decode("zlib").split("\n\n")[id(list())%7-1]
```

Note: This does not used random function, so it will be not so random like others does.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 74 chars

Run with `perl -M5.010`.

```
$-=rand 6;$_="-----
|0 2|
|4";s/\d/$->$&?o:$"/ge;say$_,$-&1?$":o,~~reverse
```

(Note that the newlines in the listing are part of the string, and not just inserted for legibility.)

If you find yourself wondering what the heck the `$->$` operation does, the following reading notes may be helpful:

- The variable `$-` automatically truncates its assigned value to an integer.
- The variable `$"` is preset to a single space.
- `o` is a bareword (representing `"o"`).

Answer (score 4):

First time golfer

### Python, 161 chars

```
from random import*
n=randint(1,7)    
o,x='o '
a='-'*5
b=(x,o)[n>3]
d=(x,o)[n>5]
c=(x,o)[n>1]    
print a+'\n|'+c+x+b+'|\n|'+d+(x,o)[n%2]+d+'|\n|'+b+x+c+'|\n'+a
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>215</s> <s>213</s> <s>212</s> <s>145</s> 135

```
r=Math.random()*6|0;alert('-----\n|'+[r>2?'o o':r?'o  ':'   ',r%2?r>3?'o o':'   ':' o ',r>2?'o o':r?'  o':'   '].join('|\n|')+'|\n-----');
```

Beat mellamokb, but I changed my original solution completely. If you want this to look good, use Google Chrome or something, change `alert` to `console.log`, and voilà.

Edit: borrowed mellamokb's |0 trick to save some characters.

Comment: @minitech: BTW, your `M=Math` trick that I tried to steal actually ends up being one character *longer*

Comment: @mellamokb: I know, I thought originally that I would use it more...

Comment: @minitech: You can save two chars with `[s.substr(0,3),s.substr(3,3),s.substr(6,3)].join('|\n|')`

Comment: @mellamokb: Nope; `s` is an array. I'm going to restart and try again.

Comment: @minitech: Here we go again :-) Evolution of the best answer by competition.  Now I'm down to 137, but you can borrow one of my tricks and save possibly 10 chars.

Comment: @minitech: Love the `x?x?x:x:x`.  Didn't know you could do that without any parens, lol!  Wow and `x?x:x?x:x`?  Impressive and creative.  I'm learning so much through these exercises :-)

Comment: @minitech: pssst. mutual up-vote?

Comment: @minitech: Wow are you really only 13 years old?? lol...

Comment: @mellamokb: Sure, mutual up-vote :-) Yes, I'm 13 also.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but... any time you have a 3-char constant string that you use at least 3 times (`'   '` in this case) it is better to put it into a variable. Doing that and changing how the join is done will knock 9 chars off the above (I see 137 for the above if you ignore the `;` at the end, but this version is 128 chars): `r=Math.random(d='-----',z='|   |',t='|o o|')*6|0;alert([d,r>2?t:r?'|o  |':z,r%2?r>3?t:z:'| o |',r>2?t:r?'|  o|':z,d].join('\n'))`.

Answer (score 4):

## **Common Lisp 170**

```
(let*((r(random 6))(a "-----
|")(c "o")(d " ")(e "|
|")(f(concatenate 'string a(if(< r 1)d c)d(if(< r 3)d c)e(if(> r 4)c ))))(concatenate 'string f(if(evenp r)c d)(reverse f)))
```

Note that the newlines are significant.  Unlike these silly "modern" languages, Common Lisp favors readability over succinctness, so we have the cumbersome "concatenate 'string..." construct and no succinct way to reference a character in a string.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (<strike>169</strike> <strike>168</strike> <strike>141</strike> 137)

```
r=Math.random()*6|0;s='-----\n|'+(r>0?'o ':'  ')+(r>2?'o':' ')+'|\n|'+(r-5?' ':'o');alert(s+(r%2?' ':'o')+s.split('').reverse().join(''))
```

Doesn't look quite right in `alert` because it's not fixed-width font, but rest assured it is correct, or test by emitting a `<pre>` tag and doing `writeln` :-)

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/d4YTn/3/ (only works in JS 1.7-compliant browsers, such as FF2+)

Credits: Hacked `Math` trick from @minitech and die print logic from @Keith.

**Edit**: Remove `Math` trick from @minitech because it actually made it *longer* :-)

**Edit 2**: Save 17 chars. Borrow trick from @Keith for taking advantage of dice symmetry.  Use trick for simplifying converting random number to int.

**Edit 3**: Remove `1+` to shift random number from 1-6 to 0-5 and save 2 chars.  As a result, I can also change `r%2-1` to `r%2` and save another 2 chars.

**Edit 4**: jsfiddle is working again. Updated :-)

Comment: E4X! And I can't believe Chrome won't support it!

Comment: Heh, I beat you finally :)

Comment: Two characters, now, using your `|0` trick :-)

Comment: It works in Chrome for me.

Answer (score 3):

**PHP 119 <strike>126</strike> <strike>128</strike> <strike>131</strike> <strike>188</strike> <strike>201</strike> <strike>213</strike> <strike>234</strike> <strike>239</strike>**

```
<?$c=($r=rand()%6)%2?$r>4?'o ':'  ':' o';$b=$r>0?$r<3?'o  ':'o o':'   ';echo$a="-----\n|$b|\n|$c",substr(strrev($a),1);
```

Comment: The closing `?>` can be omitted, saving you 2 characters.

Comment: You can inline the declaration for `$r`, saving another character. The space after `echo` can be omitted as well. You can inline the initialization of `$a` too, bringing you to 128. Putting line breaks directly into the string instead of escaping them with `\n` saves another two characters, then.

Answer (score 3):

**Python** **108** <strike>114</strike> <strike>119</strike> <strike>121</strike> <strike>122</strike> <strike>129</strike>

wtf! looks like 1st solution ?! but iam not ... cheater

108

```
import random as R
i=R.randint(1,6)
X=' 0'
A='-----\n|%s %s|\n|'%(X[i>1],X[i>3])+X[i>5]
print A+X[i%2]+A[::-1]
```

119

```
import random as R
i=R.randint(1,6)
X=' 0';a=X[i>5]
A='-----\n|%s %s|\n|%s|'%(X[i>1],X[i>3],a+X[i%2]+a)
print A+A[-6::-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Python 133

```
import random as R
i=R.randint(1,6)
a='   ';b='0 0'
A='-----\n|'+((a,'0  ')[i>1],b)[i>3]+'|\n|'
print A+((a,' 0 ')[i%2],b)[i>5]+A[::-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

### F# - <strike>165</strike> 161 characters

```
(System.Random()).Next 6|>fun x->[for y in[x>0;x%2=0;x>2;x=5]->if y then"o"else" "]|>fun[a;b;c;d]->printf"-----\n|%s %s|\n|%s%s%s|\n|%s %s|\n-----"a c d b d c a
```

Answer (score 3):

#### perl - <strike>111</strike> <strike>103</strike> 101

```
$n=int rand 6;
($t="-----\n|0 1|\n|232|\n|1 0|\n-----\n")=~s/(\d)/5639742>>6*$1>>$n&1?o:$"/eg;
die$t;
```

Comment: +1 for using `die` instead of `print`/`say`

Answer (score 3):

### APL (69)

```
5 5⍴(5⍴'-'),{⊃⍵↓' o|'}¨2,(⌽M),2,2,(N∊¨6(1 3 5)6),2,2,2,⍨M←3 6 1>⍨N←?6
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Golfscript <s>80</s> 65

```
6rand):^;'-'5*n+:_[^6&0^4&^6=].^1&+-1%+3/{'|'\{'o'' 'if+}/'|'n}/_
```

The program can be tested [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=NnJhbmQpOl47Jy0nNSpuKzpfW142JjBeNCZeNj1dLl4xJistMSUrMy97J3wnXHsnbycnICdpZit9Lyd8J259L18=&run=true)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, *154* <strike>162</strike> <strike>167</strike> <strike>172</strike> chars

```
import System.Random
main=randomRIO(1::Int,6)>>=putStrLn. \x->let{h="-----\n|"++c(>1):' ':c(>3):"|\n|"++[c(>5)];c f|f x='o'|True=' '}in h++c odd:reverse h
```

It uses roughly the same idea as the Python one.

Readable version:

```
import System.Random

main = do
    x <- randomRIO (1 :: Int, 6)
    putStrLn (render x)

render x = str ++ check odd ++ reverse str
  where
    str = concat
        [ "-----\n|"
        , check (> 1)
        , " "
        , check (> 3)
        , "|\n|"
        , check (> 5)
        ]
    check f = if f x then "o" else " "
```

Answer (score 2):

**PHP 126 <strike>127</strike> <strike>179</strike>**

```
<?$x=($r=rand(1,6))>3?"o o":($r<2?"   ":"o  ");$z=$r>5?"o o":($r%2==0?"   ":" o ");$v="-----\n|$x|\n";echo"$v|$z|".strrev($v);
```

Another PHP solution. I came to the almost same solution by Oleg.

Answer (score 2):

**C** - 215

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main(){char a[]=A,b[]=B,c=3,d=(srand(time(0)),rand()%6+1),e=d-2;if(d==1)a[5]=C;else{while(--e>-1)a[b[D[d-3]-48+e]-48]=C;a[0]=a[10]=C;}p(E);while(--c>-1)p("|%s|\n",a+c*4);p(E);}
```

Compiles with:

```
cl /DA="\"   \0   \0   \"" /DB="\"5282582468\"" /DC='o' /DD="\"0136\"" /DE="\"+---+\n\"" /Dp=printf dice.c
```

Comment: Is that sorta cheating with all those flags on the command-line?  I don't understand it the /DA /DB /DC.. thing.

Comment: My compiler does not understand the `/D` switch... Please don't cheat by putting random defines into the compilation command.

Answer (score 2):

### Python (153)

This is by far not the smallest submission, i just thought it looked nice :)

```
import random as r
print"""-----
|%c %c|
|%c%c%c|
|%c %c|
-----"""%tuple(
r.choice([
"   o   ",
"o     o",
"o  o  o",
"oo   oo",
"oo o oo",
"ooo ooo"]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Q (120 chars)

```
dice:{(`t`e`l`c`r`w!5 cut"-----|   ||o  || o ||  o||o o|")(,/)(`t;(`e`c`e;`l`e`r;`l`c`r;`w`e`w;`w`c`w;`w`w`w)(*)1?6;`t)}
```

Usage:

```
dice[]
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, <del>168</del> <del>164</del> 163 chars

Sorry if I'm a bit late to the party, but since no answer has been accepted yet, and the only other C solution was somewhat longer, here goes...

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){srand(time(0));char*o="O ",r=rand()%6,i=o[r<1],j=o[r<3],k=o[r<5];printf("-----\n|%c %c|\n|%c%c%c|\n|%c %c|\n-----\n",i,j,k,o[r&1],k,j,i);}
```

You can remove the include and save another 18 chars, but then it doesn't compile without warnings.

**Edit**:
using [user23241's command-line trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2662/4208), the shortest C code that produces the result (without compiler warnings) is only 12 chars:

```
#include I
M
```

At least if you cheat and use the following command line to compile:

```
gcc -DI="<stdio.h>" -DM="main(){srand(time(0));char*o=\"O \",r=rand()%6,i=o[r<1],j=o[r<3],k=o[r<5];printf(\"-----\n|%c %c|\n|%c%c%c|\n|%c %c|\n-----\n\",i,j,k,o[r&1],k,j,i);}" dice.c -o dice
```

Answer (score 2):

## c, 140 chars

```
r,i,s;main(){srand(time(i=0));r=rand()%6;for(s=-1;i-=s;)putchar("\n|   |-o"[i>5?i==8&&r||i==10&&2<r||i==14&&4<r||i==15&&(s=1)&~r?7:i%6:6]);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP:1284

This is my second CodeGolf, and I wasn't really aiming for shortness as much as code mutability and matching the gaming criteria.

You can generate 4 sided dice as well as 6 sided.

Maybe later I will shorten it and make it a little more dynamic.

```
function draw_dice($numdice=1,$sides=4)
{
/* Verify acceptable parameters. */
if($sides<4){die("You must choose 4 sides or greater.");}
if($numdice<1){die("You must have at least one dice.");}
/* End verification */
$a=' ';
$b=' ';
$c=' ';
$d=' ';
$e=' ';
$f=' ';
$g=' ';
$h=' ';
$i=' ';
$j=' ';

switch($sides)
{
case $sides%2==0:
if($sides==4)
{
$ran=rand(1,$sides);
switch($ran)
{
case 1:
$e="o";
break;
case 2:
$a="o";
$j="o";
break;
case 3:
$b="o";
$g="o";
$j="o";
break;
case 4:
$a="o";
$c="o";
$g="o";
$j="o";
break;
}
echo "<div style='text-align:center;display:inline-block;'>";
echo " - <br/>";
echo "| |<br/>";
echo "|$a$b$c|<br/>";
echo "| $d$e$f |<br/>";
echo "|  $g$h$i$j  |<br/>";
echo "---------<br/>";
echo "</div>";

}

if($sides==6)
{
$ran=rand(1,$sides);
switch($ran)
{
case 1:
$e="o";
break;
case 2:
$a="o";
$i="o";
break;
case 3:
$a="o";
$i="o";
$e="o";
break;
case 4:
$a="o";
$c="o";
$g="o";
$i="o";
break;
case 5:
$a="o";
$c="o";
$g="o";
$i="o";
$e="o";
break;
case 6:
$a="o";
$c="o";
$d="o";
$f="o";
$g="o";
$i="o";
break;
}
echo "-----<br/>";
echo "|$a$b$c|<br/>";
echo "|$d$e$f|<br/>";
echo "|$g$h$i|<br/>";
echo "-----<br/>";
}

if($sides!==4&&$sides!==6)
{
die("Only 4 and 6 sided are supported at this time.");
}

break;

case $sides%2==1:
die("Must have even number of sides.");
break;
}

}

draw_dice(1,4);
```

### Output 4 sided:

```
    - 
   | |
  |o o|
 |     |
|  o  o  |
---------
```

### Output 6 sided:

```
-----
|o  |
| o |
|  o|
-----
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript 220 bytes

```
r=(1+Math.random()*6|0).toString(2).split("").reverse();b=r[1];c=r[2];s=[[b|c,0,c],[b&c,1&r[0],b&c],[c,0,b|c]];"-----\n|"+s.map(function(v){return v.map(function(w){return w?"o":" "}).join("")}).join("|\n|")+"|\n-----";
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 5.4, 107 bytes

```
<?$r=rand(1,6);$d=[' ','o'];$o='+---+
|'.$d[$r>1].' '.$d[$r>3].'|
|'.$d[$r>5];echo$o.$d[$r%2].strrev($o);
```

**102 bytes***

```
<?$r=rand(1,6);$d=' o';$o='+---+
|'.$d[$r>1].' '.$d[$r>3].'|
|'.$d[$r>5];echo$o.$d[$r%2].strrev($o);
```

**Unfortunately, the 102 byte version issues notices due to the casting of `bool` to `int` when indexing the string `$d`. Other than that, it works fine.*

Comment: The byte counts seem to be 105 and 100, respectively.

Comment: Ah, I must've accounted for the newlines.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ruby , <strike>134 132 119 118 117 112</strike> 111 chars,

My second golf in life. I've used magic numbers.
Any advises please?

```
r=?-*5+"
|"+((a=:ghklm[rand 6])?a.to_i(36).to_s(2).tr("10","o "):"    o").insert(3,"|
|")
$><<r+r[0,14].reverse
```

Outputs:

```
ice@distantstar ~/virt % ruby ./golf.rb
-----
|o o|
|   |
|o o|
-----
ice@distantstar ~/virt % ruby ./golf.rb
-----
|o o|
|o o|
|o o|
-----
ice@distantstar ~/virt % ruby ./golf.rb
-----
|   |
| o |
|   |
-----
ice@distantstar ~/virt %
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <strike>166</strike> <strike>161 146</strike> 143 chars

```
a="O  ";b=" O ";c="  O";d="   ";e="O O";RandomInteger@{1, 6}/.Thread@Rule[Range@6,{{d,b,d},{a,d,c},{a,b,c},{e,d,e},{e,b,e}, {e,e,e}}]//MatrixForm
```

Sample Output:

[image: five]

---

If the matrix braces offend, you may replace `MatrixForm` with `TableForm` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

### VimScript – 169 chararacters

Note that this is not pure Vim since Vim has no builtin random number generator. There are extensions that can be downloaded for it of course, but since I am a diehard Linux man, I thought, why not just rely on the shell environment instead.

#### Code

```
norm5a-^[YPo|   |^[YPP
let x=system('echo $RANDOM')%6+1
if x<2
norm jllro
el
norm lrolljj.k
if x>3
norm k.hjj
en
if x>2
norm h.k
en
if x>5
norm .l
en
if x>4
norm l.
en
en
```

#### Explanation

- The first line generators the "box" that represents the die.
- The second line fetches a random number from the environment and using modular arithmetic forces it to be a valid number for a dice.
- The remaining lines move around the die face filling in the `o` 's. Note that this is meant to be optimized for the least number of characters, not the least number of movements (i.e. there would be faster ways in turns of keystrokes if I was doing it manually—doing the `if`s all in my head).
- As always, `^` is not a literal `^` but an indication of an escape sequence.

#### Testing

Change `RANDOM` to `DICEVALUE`, save the VimScript code into `dice.vim`, then run this shell script on it, giving as arguments whatever numbers you want to test:

```
#!/bin/sh
for DICEVALUE in $@; do
    export DICEVALUE
    vim -S dice.vim
done
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>117</s> 99 bytes

```
N=RND(6)B=N>2?"-"*5L!!N*5-B*2L!(N<<31)*4-(N>4)L!!N+B*2?"-"*5DEF L I?"|";MID$("   o o  ",I,3);"|
END
```

[Output](http://12me21.github.io/syntax/linkc#-----%0A%7C%20%20%20%7C%0A%7C%20o%20%7C%0A%7C%20%20%20%7C%0A-----%0A%0A-----%0A%7Co%20%20%7C%0A%7C%20%20%20%7C%0A%7C%20%20o%7C%0A-----%0A%0A-----%0A%7Co%20%20%7C%0A%7C%20o%20%7C%0A%7C%20%20o%7C%0A-----%0A%0A-----%0A%7Co%20o%7C%0A%7C%20%20%20%7C%0A%7Co%20o%7C%0A-----%0A%0A-----%0A%7Co%20o%7C%0A%7C%20o%20%7C%0A%7Co%20o%7C%0A-----%0A%0A-----%0A%7Co%20o%7C%0A%7Co%20o%7C%0A%7Co%20o%7C%0A-----)

Cheating version:
`?""[RND(6)]` ([What it looks like in SmileBASIC's font](http://12Me21.github.io/syntax/link#%3F%22%EE%88%BA%EE%88%BB%EE%88%BB%EE%88%BD%EE%88%BE%EE%88%BF%22%5BRND(6)%5D))

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 38 bytes

```
3`|% |%%`-3/ømvøm⁋»∧⁰¾×O↓»b7ẇ℅ƛ‛o $i;%
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=3%60%7C%25%20%7C%25%25%60-3%2F%C3%B8mv%C3%B8m%E2%81%8B%C2%BB%E2%88%A7%E2%81%B0%C2%BE%C3%97O%E2%86%93%C2%BBb7%E1%BA%87%E2%84%85%C6%9B%E2%80%9Bo%20%24i%3B%25&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
=== Part 1: Construct the dice ===
         -         # Prepend...
3                  # Literal
         -         # Minuses to...
 `|% |%%`          # Literal
          3/       # Into 3 pieces
            ømvøm  # Quad palindromise
                 ⁋ # Newline joined
=== Part 2: Roll the dice ===
»...»             # Compressed base-2 integer containing bits for each
     b            # To bits
      7ẇ℅         # Choose a random group of 7
         ƛ     ;  # Map...
          ‛o $i   # o or space depending on if its truthy
                % # Format above with this
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <sup>58 55</sup> 52 bytes

```
?@6{' o|-'{~6 3 3(3,~3,2,.,.&2)"2@$#:@36b3igm68ktg7p
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FNVUtFK8NYM0UrS3V1LiU99TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrcdPE3sGsWl0hv0ZXvbrOTMFYwVjDWKfOWMdIR09HT81IU8nIQUXZysHYLMk4Mz3XzCK7JN28AKJ3vSZXanJGvkKakraCoYGKIUR0wQIIDQA)

- `6 3 3... $#:@36b3igm68ktg7p` Generate all dice patterns from a single base 36 number containing all the bits.
- `(3,~3,2,.,.&2)"2` Add the frame integers.
- `' o|-'{~` Convert to ascii.
- `?@6{` Randomly choose one.